# Set Label Text with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onchange

This should be quite straight forward, however the following code does not do anything as far as changing the next label's text. I have tried using .text, .html, and so on to no avail. Is there anything wrong with this code?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("input:checkbox").on("change", checkboxChange);

    function checkboxChange()
    {
        $("#"+this.id).next("label").text("TESTTTT");
    }
});
</script>



<td width="15%" align="center"><input type="checkbox" name="task1" id="task1"></td>
<td width="25%" align="center"><label for="task1"></label></td>
```

Comment: Put some HTML code here

Comment: `.next` only applies to direct siblings. Your `label` is not on the same DOM level as your `input`. You'd be better off using that `for` attribute in a selector

Comment: checkboxchange() is a function...u forgot to use paranthesis :P

Comment: @TusharGupta no, he is using the referenced function, not the returned value of this function

Answer (score 25):

The checkbox is in a `td`, so need to get the parent first:

```
$("input:checkbox").on("change", function() {
    $(this).parent().next().find("label").text("TESTTTT");
});
```

Alternatively, find a label which has a `for` with the same `id` (perhaps more performant than reverse traversal) :

```
$("input:checkbox").on("change", function() {
    $("label[for='" + $(this).attr('id') + "']").text("TESTTTT");
});
```

Or, to be more succinct just `this.id`:

```
$("input:checkbox").on("change", function() {
    $("label[for='" + this.id + "']").text("TESTTTT");
});
```

Comment: @BrettPowell you should use FOR attribute of label instead

Comment: `this.id` is fine, no need to wrap it as a jQuery object

Comment: @A.Wolff: yes, i inittially wanted to show the problem and was editing the answer to show with for.

Comment: So now you have a complete answer +1

Comment: This work good. Do you refer any books to know about this kind of selector and functions

Comment: @sun: you may want to start with this: http://www.learningjquery.com/ although not a book, but the entire site is available as a 5mb download if you wish.

Answer (score 8):

I would just query for the `for` attribute instead of repetitively recursing the DOM tree.

```
$("input:checkbox").on("change", function() {
    $("label[for='"+this.id+"']").text("TESTTTT");
});
```

Answer (score -2):

You can try:

```
<label id ="label_id"></label>
 $("#label_id").html('value');
```